# Print Data from MySQL Database to Console from Python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with a Python Console environment. I have a MySQL database set up which I can connect to successfully. I can also Insert data into the DB. Now I'm trying to display/fetch data from it.

I connect fine, and it seems I'm fetching data from my database, but nothing is actually printing to the console. I want to be able to fetch and display data, but nothing is displaying at all.

How do I actually display the data I select?

```
#importing module Like Namespace in .Net
import pypyodbc
#creating connection Object which will contain SQL Server Connection
connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=DESKTOP-NJR6F8V\SQLEXPRESS;Data Source=DESKTOP-NJR6F8V\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False')
cursor = connection.cursor()
SQLCommand = ("SELECT ID FROM MyAI_DB.dbo.WordDefinitions WHERE ID > 117000")
#Processing Query
cursor.execute(SQLCommand)
#Commiting any pending transaction to the database.
connection.commit()
#closing connection
#connection.close()
```

Comment: use the following link and use the fetch tools
https://github.com/jiangwen365/pypyodbc

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I failed to include the right Print statement. Which was:

```
print(cursor.fetchone())
```

I also had the connection.commit statement in the wrong place (it was inserted even executing the Print statement). The final code that worked was this:

```
#importing module Like Namespace in .Net
import pypyodbc
#creating connection Object which will contain SQL Server Connection
connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=DESKTOP-NJR6F8V\SQLEXPRESS;Data Source=DESKTOP-NJR6F8V\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False')
cursor = connection.cursor()
SQLCommand = ("SELECT * FROM MyAI_DB.dbo.WordDefinitions")
#Processing Query
cursor.execute(SQLCommand)
#Commiting any pending transaction to the database.
print(cursor.fetchone())
connection.commit()
#closing connection
#connection.close()
```