# How to remove Special Characters and Spacing from Python Console Application?

Tags: python, mysql, console

[image]I am Selecting data from a MySQL database that is displayed in a Console. This is being done through running commands in a connected Python application.

For the sake of readability, I'm trying to omit all the extra erroneous spacing and special characters that the Console seems to add in the output (see image).

Is there a setting or code to just pull the actual text I entered, on 1 clean line, instead of all the extra [' and whitespace line breaks ?

Comment: Would be helpful if you an show your code that does the print. Otherwise a simple `.trim()` to the string might get you what you need.

Comment: Reading your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/q/50010897/1292238 I think the simple way is not to `print(cursor.fetchone())` but to `print(cursor.fetchone()['user_name'])`, where `'user_name'` should be replaced with the actual attribute name that corresponds to `'Dennis'`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `SELECT` statement, do this to trim trailing whitespace:

```
SELECT RTRIM(Name) FROM MyTable;
```

Then, (assuming Python 3), do:

```
print('Welcome back', cursor.fetchone()[0])
```

The expected output would be:

```
Welcome back Dennis
```